# Should we have book-specific Harry Potter tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've Harry Potter questions beating any other canon by hundreds of questions. Should we also add book-specific tags like *deathly-hallows*, *chamber-of-secrets* etc. to a question if applicable?

---

**My personal opinion:** Yes. It'd be useful for a guy to visit questions from a book after reading it.

Comment: We already have a [deathly-hallows] tag, and that’s used for the objects, not the books. Do we create a new tag for the books, or double up the existing one?

Comment: I support this proposal. There are [fellowship-of-the-ring] and [the-two-towers] tags (though oddly not a [return-of-the-king] tag) and also an [a-memory-of-light] tag for the last book of the Wheel of Time series.

Comment: @randal'thor Those book-specific tags also appear to be almost unused compared to the main LOTR tag.

Comment: Note also that book-specific tags for *Chamber* and *Order* (at least) have existed previously and been burninated by the community.

Answer (score 5):

I say **no**, given the number of tags that can be used to further specify the Harry-Potter questions, by character, object, type of magic, or whether it's the books or movies being put to question.